# GRPC stream close connect

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-go

I am writing a server handle data stream on `golang` using `grpc`. After recive a request, I should put this stream to a `Chan`, then a
`goroutine` handle this request and send back. But I get a `rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing` when I write back to client in the `goroutine`. So I wonder if I can pass `stream` to `Channel`, does this operation close the connection?

here is Recognize in protocol buffer

```
service AsrService {
     rpc Recognize(stream RecognizeRequest) returns (stream RecognizeResponse) {}
}
```

here is automatic generation using grpc

```
type AsrService_RecognizeServer interface {
    Send(*RecognizeResponse) error
    Recv() (*RecognizeRequest, error)
    grpc.ServerStream
}
```

here is put stream to Chan

```
func (s *ScheduleServer) Recognize(stream 
AsrService_RecognizeServer) error {
    req, err := stream.Recv() // I can use Recv here
    if err == io.EOF || err != nil {
        // do something
    }
    var asrRequest ASRRequest
    asrRequest.stream = &stream //pass stream to Chan
    ASRRequestChan <- &asrRequest

    return nil
}
```

Here is a goroutine to handle the Chan

```
type ASRRequest struct {
    stream AsrService_RecognizeServer
}

var ClientRequestChan = make(chan *ClientRequest, 200)
func HandlRequestChan() {
    for {
        select {
            case r := <- ClientRequestChan:
                Log.Infof("Chan get request info[%v]", r)
                var rsp RecognizeResponse
                rsp.Code = **
                streamInter := *r.stream
                err = streamInter.Send(&rsp) // I can use Send here
                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Printf("Grpc write failed,err[%v]", err)
                }
                fmt.Printf("return time[%v]\n",time.Now().UnixNano() / 1e6)
        }
    }    
}
```

then I get error rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing, so is the stream closed after pass it to the Chan? Because if I do not use Chan, it can send result to client successfully.

Comment: Returning from the stream handler means that the server is done sending messages. That closes the connection with that client. After sending to `ASRRequestChan`, you have no other synchronization. The handler returns, and the next time you call `streamInter.Send(&rsp)` the connection is closed.

Comment: With that said, the code you presented is declared as a bidirectional streaming, but in your stream handler you are receiving only once — and also sending once. So that's not a stream. It could be a simple RPC, or server-side streaming instead.

Comment: @blackgreen I see, you mean `Recognize` function returned after put the `stream` in the `Chan`, so the connection is closed after `Recognize` returned. Right?

Comment: yes. The usual practice to handle streams is to call stream.Recv in a loop

Comment: @blackgreen I build a child `goroutine` to handle the request and use the `sync.WaitGroup` to make sure the `Recognize` will not return until child `goroutine` finish .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I change the strategy and use `sync.WaitGroup` to make sure `main goroutine` do not return until the `stream` send back. I will build a `goroutine` to handle this `stream`, and the `main goroutine` does not return until the `child goroutine` finish. So the connect will not close.

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
func (s *ScheduleServer) Recognize(stream pb.AsrService_RecognizeServer) error {
    wg.Add(1)
    go s.Recognize_Syn(&wg, stream)

    wg.Wait()
    return nil
}

func (s *ScheduleServer) Recognize_Syn(wg *sync.WaitGroup, stream pb.AsrService_RecognizeServer) error {
    defer wg.Done()
    //do something
    err = stream.Send(&rsp)
    return nil
}
```