# grpc stream in golang if the handler does not return will it cause memory/performance problems

Tags: go, stream, grpc

I'm trying to do something very similar to this [GRPC stream close connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69189001/grpc-stream-close-connect).  From the comments mentioned here, I should not return from the handler until the stream is closed.  However if I have around 100, possibly 1000s clients connecting then you could have potentially 1000s of handlers which have not returned, would this cause a bottlenect on the server ?  I mean then its technically handling 1000s of concurrent requests right since the handlers have not returned ?

Comment: Yes. A stream in some cases is more desirable & less load on a server as it's reusing an existing network connection. Opening & closing connections to make "short" calls generates more load on a server.

Comment: I'm actually talking about keeping a stream open by just keeping the handler running indefenitely.

Comment: let me clarify a bit more, I'm developing a simple chat application with grpc streaming.  Each client will have a grpc stream client, this means the handler on the sever end will have to run indefinitely or until the client closes the connection.  So in this scenario, we could have 1000s of handlers non-exiting which could limit the number of concurrent connections ?

Comment: Stackoverflow is a code-centric site - and not well suited for broad design discussion which can be quite opinionated. Having said that, if you want realtime app response - which is pretty much what a chat app demands - then  streaming is the way to go. Every resource has its limits. There are plenty of mechanism out there to horizontally scale a service, `k8s` replicas etc.